# not able to find .FindControl while coding in rowupdating event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a grid with 3 columns `empName, bonus, Id`

I wanted to implement edit functionality on gridview.

For that i went into editTemplates and added 3 textboxes:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBonus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

I am refering to [THIS](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread14197-how-to-insert-update-and-delete-in-gridview-in-aspnet.aspx) doccument for the code.

According to this i tried to write code like:

```
TextBox txtUname = (TextBox)gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmpName");
```

But after `(TextBox)gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].` it is not showing me `FindControl`

Is there any mistake in the steps i have followed for this procedure?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextBox txtUname = (TextBox)gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmpName");
```

instead use Rows as

```
TextBox txtUname = (TextBox)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmpName");
```

And it should be `"EditItemTemplate"` instead of `"EmptyDataTemplate"`

Comment: with item template should it be done with only one textbox?, beacuse text boxes are comming besides edit button, instead i wanted to recognize text box on column when we press edit button

Comment: If you are in EditMode, EditTemplete will appear. If you want TextBox by Default, you can create any number of Textbox in ItemTemplate. ultimately, you can find control from Row if the control exists in respective template. refer these 2 tutorials for more information about templates 1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288031.aspx  2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i am trying on further. If any difficulty regarding same issue i will add comment

Comment: please see this question now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468212/null-value-in-findcontrol-of-gridview-item-template-confusion

Answer (score 1):

The DataKeys and DataKeyNames are used to store values that you define in the gridview.
What you simply need is

```
TextBox txtUname = (TextBox)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmpName");
```

In case you want to know more how DataKeys can be used try google or check out this example :

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=291

Comment: but i want to ask, which is this text box 'txtEmpName' ? Is this one i added in EmptyDataTemplate ?

Comment: Find your answer in my Comment in my answer post