# null value in findcontrol of gridview, item template confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have Template Field for gridview as below:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBonus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

When i am in `gv_RowUpdating` event, i wanted to take the value of edited field by findcontrol.

For that i am using following code:

```
`TextBox txtUname = (TextBox)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmpName");`
```

But each time it is showing me `null` value in `txtUname` when i debug the code.

What can be the problem?

Full Event Code:

```
 protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                TextBox txtUname = (TextBox)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmpName");

                float bonus = float.Parse(gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["bonus"].ToString());

                try
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("update emp set empName=@eName");
                    cmd.parameters.AddParametersWithValue("@eName",txtUname.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
```

**EDIT**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.51.71;Initial Catalog=WebBasedNewSoft;User ID=sa;password=prabhu");

            BindGrid();
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from emp", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.EditIndex;

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

            string eName = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text.ToString().Trim();

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update emp set empName='"+eName+"'",con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show full event function??

Comment: @AmitSingh yes, sure, just a minute.

Comment: @AmitSingh pasted the function

Comment: pls don't use two edit template use single..like this `<EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBonus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton></EditItemTemplate>`

Comment: but this shows me textboxes besides edit link button

Comment: try it and check it..wheater it work or not ...you can put your edit button in next column...

Comment: how are you binding the gridview? Add more code please.

Comment: To keep Edit button aside you can use Table to display control within Templates. So no need to use 2 EditItemTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt

also put your code for Edit command. it might be RowEditing or RowCommand

Comment: what should i do to take value from that default textbox with each field which comes after i press edit link?

Comment: Nothing. refer this code. you just set EditIndex and bind the grid again, you will get the value into your textboxes. make sure you have set binding to controls....  protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
   {
   
   GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
   showgrid();
   }

Comment: sir, control is now getting the value, but when i edit the value in textbox,and presses update button, page gets refreshed and shows me the old value.

Comment: Are you saving the updated values into Database ? if yes, Rebind the grid. if no, change the values into the datasource you used, then rebind the grid.

Comment: sir, please see my edit, i had done that, that is my full serverside code

Comment: put   BindGrid(); at last in GridView1_RowUpdating method. also make sure there is no exception. and I noticed one thing that, your query does not have where condition while updating. once your query will be executed, all records will be updated. please put where condition into that.